# In a client-server program how to pass hexadecimal values

Tags: c, hex

In a client server program I have to try a buffer overflow attack for a lab exercise. I need to pass a shell code with the input string to the server program. In the shell code there are some values as `\x00` but the server terminates the string as soon as it reads `\x00`.

My shell code is like this:

```
\x55\x48\x89\xe5\x48\x83\xec\x20\xc7\x45\xe0\x59\x6f\x75\x20\xc7\x45\xe4\x6c\x6f
\x73\x65\x66\xc7\x45\xe8\x21\xba\x98\x0e\x40\x00\xb8\x09\x0e\x40\x00\x48\x89\xd6
```

My server terminates the string as soon as it sees `\x00`.

Please suggest a way to overcome this.

Comment: Its a client server program.. I have to try a buffer overflow attack for a lab exercise. I need to pass a shell code with the input string to the server program. In the shell code there are some values as \x00 but the server terminates the string as soon as it reads \x00

Comment: You need to design your shell code to avoid the null byte, `\x00`, precisely because it tends to be the last character in strings.  One of the arts of writing good shell code is precisely 'avoid the null byte'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass your shellcode which contains null character to your application while it contains null character as you mentioned. Actually you should change your shellcode. If I remember correctly you could tell Metasploit to not generate specific characters while generating shellcode (in your case: null character).

Comment: I am unable to find the link. Could you please guide me to the link where I can find details regarding this.

Comment: You should have Metasploit installed. Kali Linux has it by default. You can download it and use it live. This link explains everything you need in detail: http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Generating_Payloads

Comment: Thanks for your help!! Appreciate it!!

Comment: Your welcome. Accepting my comment will be appreciated too ;)